# Vector of pointers to template abstract class?

Tags: c++, templates, generics, compiler-errors, abstract-class

Can someone tell me why the following code fails to compile? I've tried to figure this out myself, but every answer I've found seems to be slightly different than the issue at hand. Here is the result of an attempt at compilation:

```
jefferson@ubuntu:~$ g++ -std=c++14 templates.cpp
templates.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
templates.cpp:26:19: error: template argument 1 is invalid
   std::vector<Foo*> flubs;
                   ^
templates.cpp:26:19: error: template argument 2 is invalid
```

Here is the code in question:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <vector>
  3 template <class T>
  4 class Foo {
  5   public:
  6     virtual void f() const = 0;
  7 };
  8
  9 class Bar : public Foo<Bar> {
 10   public:
 11     void f() const { printf("foobar\n"); };
 12 };
 13
 14 class Baz : public Foo<Baz> {
 15   public:
 16     void f() const { printf("foobaz\n"); };
 17 };
 18
 19 int
 20 main()
 21 {
 22   Bar bar = Bar();
 23   Baz baz = Baz();
 24   bar.f();
 25   baz.f();
 26   std::vector<Foo*> flubs;
 27   return 0;
 28 }
```

Comment: `template<class T> class Foo` is a template class. There is no `Foo` class (sans-template), and thus there is no `Foo*`

Comment: Why is `Foo` a template class? Can you not achieve the functionality you want with a non-generic `Foo` class?

Comment: Why is Foo a template? It is not using its template parameter.

Comment: It's just a toy program to illustrate the real issue I was having.

Comment: @Xirema, n.m., I see what you mean, and you're right, templates are not necessary here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Foo` is a class template, not a class.

Hence, you cannot create a pointer with the type `Foo*`.

A work around to this is to create a base class.

```
class FooBase
{
   public:
      virtual void f() const = 0;
};

template <class T>
class Foo : public FooBase
{
};
```

and then use:

```
std::vector<FooBase*> flubs;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't take the pointer of a template class - a template class exists only for the compiler. The compiler decides which instances ('classes') are needed, and generates those; but the template class itself doesn't exist anymore in the result.

Answer (score 0):

To sum it up, you can have a `std::vector<Foo<Bar> *>`, or a `std::vector<Foo<Baz> *>`, but not both in the same container.

(Assuming you can find a good use for *vector of pointers*.)